# How can I add two of my columns in my data frame to an np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to add my two of the columns contained in my df dataframe but the error says 'DataFrame' object is not callable this is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
df.drop(['id'], 1, inplace=True)

#print(df)
x = np.array(df.drop(['S', 'T'], axis=1))
y = np.array(df(['S', 'T']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct. A `pd.DataFrame` object is *not* callable. Use `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__` or its syntactic sugar `[]` with a list of series:

```
y = np.array(df[['S', 'T']])
```

Or, better, use [`pd.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
y = df[['S', 'T']].values
```